# How to generate a litecoin address?

Tags: bitcoin

I've downloaded the litecoin client and am trying to create an address. How do I generate one? Everything I put in results in a message: The entered address "" is not a valid Litecoin address.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the litecoin-qt client with GUI?
Button "Receive coins" -> Button "+ New Address"

Alternatively you can also create addresses
on [liteaddress.org](http://liteaddress.org/).
But be sure to save it to your hard disk first and execute it offline.
Otherwise your private key (ie your right to spend the money) will travel
through the net and possibly be stolen.

Comment: Is there a client without GUI too ? in which we can generate an address using https://litecoin.info/Litecoin_API

Comment: Found it, it's named `litecoind` and is present within the `daemon` directory of Litecoin installation.